# What is a function signature and type?

Tags: rust, idioms

I found the type alias below in an Scheme interpreter I'm studying. While evaluating the AST, it recognizes a function either as a natively supported function, or as a user defined function. I understand the second part of the `Enum` definition, but the first part eludes me.

```
pub enum Function {
    Native(ValueOperation),
    Scheme(Vec<String>, Vec<Value>, Rc<RefCell<Environment>>),
}


type ValueOperation = fn(&[Value], Rc<RefCell<Environment>>) -> Result<Value, RuntimeError>;
```

How does this type alias work? Does this definition say that a `ValueOperation` is just a shorthand for a function signature? I was unable to find any mention of this idiom in the official docs/books.

What's the purpose of defining a type alias for a function signature? What can you "do" with it? Is it some sort of a function pointer?

Comment: Type aliases are explained in the [Type Aliases section of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/type-aliases.html); is there something about that which is unclear?

Comment: Yes. Namely, what's the purpose of defining a type alias for a function signature? What can you "do" with it? Is it some sort of a function pointer?

Comment: It's not a function signature; it's a function pointer type.  `const X: i32 = 0;` is to `i32` as `fn f(i32) -> String { ... }` is to `fn(i32) -> String`.  It's a type like any other type.  All this is doing is defining a function pointer type with the given signature.  That there's a type alias involved is irrelevant; it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The signature of a function describes:

- its name
- its arguments
- its result
- in the case of generic functions, its generic parameters, with potentially specific bounds

For example, if you define:

```
fn hello(s: &str) {
    println!("Hello {}", s);
}
```

The function signature is `fn hello(&str)`.

---

In Rust, each function has a unique *type*, which cannot be named.

However, if you have a function, you can also coerce it into a generic `fn` type which does not care about the identity of the function, but only about how it can be used.

For the above function, this generic type is: `fn(&str)` (or `fn(&str) -> ()` if we wish to be explicit).

---

This generic type is useful to abstract over multiple functions with a similar signature. For example:

```
fn add(left: i32, right: i32) -> i32 { left + right }
fn sub(left: i32, right: i32) -> i32 { left - right }

fn select(name: &str) -> fn(i32, i32) -> i32 {
    match name {
        "add" => add,
        "sub" => sub,
        _ => unimplemented!(),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let fun = select("add");
    println!("{} + {} = {}", 1, 2, fun(1, 2));
}
```

---

It is close to function pointers in C or C++, however unlike function pointers it cannot be null.

If you need a nullable function, you can use `Option<fn(i32, i32) -> i32>` instead.

---

And thus finally we come to this type alias: it's simply a shortcut because the generic `fn` type is long. Like any other type alias.

Comment: Perfectly explained! TYVM.

Comment: Also, by "identity of function" I assume you mean _function name_, i.e. "hello"?

Comment: @neektza: No... not really. In the case of generic functions, each instance of the generic function has its own identity, so it's a bit more complex.

Comment: Can you point me to the relevant part of the docs please (related to "function identities")?

Comment: @neektza: I don't think it's an official term. I'll remove the italics.

Comment: Regarding "each function has a unique type, which cannot be named": what does this mean? If I have `fn greet(name: &str) { println!("hello, {}", name); }`, why can't I say that `greet` has the type `fn(&str) -> ()`?

Comment: @trentcl: You could say so, but it would be inaccurate. I invite you to inspect how `Box<Fn(&str) -> ()>` is represented at the binary level => there is no data pointer (it's "1"), and instead the function to be called is in the v-table. This is only possible because each function has its own type, and therefore its own v-table.

Comment: @Matthieu Thanks. Is that only a fact about the implementation of rustc, and not a feature of the type system? Because from a theoretical standpoint it seems that there is no difference between my statement and yours. (I have no background in type theory, just trying to understand better)

Comment: @trentcl: I don't have a background in type theory so... I would expect that we can say that `fn(&str) -> ()` is a super-type of the actual type of `hello`, but this is something that should be asked to one of the rustc developers (Niko, for example).